# My action bar with settings menu in the Homepage doesn't show. It only shows on the bottom if I click the settings button

Tags: android, menu, settings, updates

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.liveupdate.app.HomepageActivity" >
<item android:id="@+id/updateStatus"
    android:title="Update"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/LogoutUser"
    android:title="Logout"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

What am I missing? The settings is only showing on the bottom when I press the left button. Is it the version I chose? because I don't see any errors showing up or anything like that. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does HomepageActivity extends ActionBarActivity (and not Activity)?

EDIT:

Check if HomepageActivity starts with:

```
public class HomepageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
....
}
```

If not (and it extends Activity), fix it and you should solve the problem.

Comment: public class HomepageActivity extends Activity. It extends to Activity.